# The resultant force on a simple pendulum bob

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, velocity, centripetal-force

At the equilibrium position of an oscillating pendulum, its acceleration is momentarily zero as the velocity reaches its maximum value. Does this mean that at the equilibrium position the resultant force is zero? But this is circular motion, meaning that it must always have a resultant force towards the centre of the circle? So is the resultant force on a simple pendulum ever zero, if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

This [animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oscillating_pendulum.gif) from this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)) demonstrates that the force/acceleration is not zero at the equilibrium position.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The resultant force is never zero.

There are two ways to think about small amplitude oscillations of simple pendulum.

One way is to think of it as a small linear motion. In that case we are only concerned with tangential motion. Tangential acceleration is zero at 'mean position'.

The second way is to think about it as an angular oscillations. In this case, angular acceleration is zero when string is vertical.

Answer (score 0):

At the midpoint, the $x$ direction force is zero; the $y$ direction force (in the centripetal direction) is not zero. If we choose $x-y$ coordinates that remain fixed and do not rotate with the pendulum, you have the force of gravity which is always downward $y$, and you have the centripetal force which is always acting in a line from the weight to the hinge point.  As the pendulum swings, this second force always has a $y$ component, and has an $x$ component that oscillates positive and negative, passing through zero at the center.